# COnfigiration file for PhpMyAdmin in linux mint

Tags: phpmyadmin

I want to connect to PhpMyAdmin with no password in linux mint 14.

When I Googled about it I found that I've to change this `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] : FALSE` in the configuration file, but I don't know where I can find this file.

Answer (score 0):

Linux Mint 16: File System->etc->phpmyadmin: config.inc.php

I'm total noob as well, just found the file though :) Be careful, changes are permanent.